# List Action of Jtable with a Where Condition

Tags: jquery, html, list, action, jquery-jtable

How to pass The value of QuestionId to CRUDcontroller "List action" and how to receive the value of QuestionId in CrudController

```
var QuestionId ;
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = window.location.href;
    var params = url.split('?');
    var str1 = params[1].replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
    QuestionId=parseInt(str1, 10);
    $('#QuestionAnswers').jtable({
        title: 'Question Answers',
        actions: {
            listAction: 'CRUDController?action=list',
            createAction:'CRUDController?action=create',
            updateAction: 'CRUDController?action=update',
            deleteAction: 'CRUDController?action=delete'
        },
        fields: {
          OptionId: {
                title:'S.NO',
                key: true,
                list: true,
                create:true
            },
           OptionValue: {
                title: 'OPTION',
                width: '30%',
                edit:true
            }    
        }
    });
    $('#QuestionAnswers').jtable('load');

});
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's not Java and has nothing to do with `javax.swing.JTable`

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I've been [retagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141732/163188) as [tag:jquery-jtable].

Comment: [Here](http://www.jtable.org/Demo/PagingAndSorting) is the simple example using MVC and Jquery-JTable